# Is there an upper limit for zoom level in MKMapView?

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, mapkit

After browsing some of the questions here, I have got a rough idea of zoom level and MKMapView. Then I found this great blog:

http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/set-the-zoom-level-of-an-mkmapview/

But when I tried out the code from that blog, I felt there seemed to be an upper limit for zoom level. That is to say, no matter how large I set zoomLevel to be, it was always clamped to some thing like 16. The corresponding longitudeDelta of this zoomLevel was 0.003433.

In this question, [MKMapView setRegion "snaps" to predefined zoom levels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3612007/mkmapview-setregion-snaps-to-predefined-zoom-levels/4598713#4598713), pseudopeach claimed that the smallest value for longitudeDelta is .0008583, instead of .003433. Anyone knows how to get to .0008583 on iPhone?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the longitudeDelta in code in following ways-

```
MKCoordinateRegion region;
region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.0008583;
region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.0008583;
[mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
```